# Difference between Exception "Ducking" and "Swallowing"

Tags: exceptions

I came across a tutorial which says this code is `Exception Ducking`

```
public class SomeClass {

void doTask() {

    try {
        //..Some Exception prone code
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
}}
```

Though, I think ducking means to just let the exception propagate up the `callstack` by just not handling or throwing, whereas this code seems to **swallow** the exception.

Does this also comes under ducking ?

Please provide some clarification on the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial seems to use the term "exception ducking" in a non-conventional way.

The code you present is indeed swallowing the exception, by catching it and doing nothing.
Ducking an exception means, as you suspected, (intentionally) letting it escape from the current function. Similar to how you would duck for an object thrown at you that you don't want to catch.